# Any way to force value of bool to read as -1/1 instead of 0/1?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean, bit

I've been using an int in my code to define a horizontal direction. This is so I could use it in my movement code (eg. position.x += speed * direction). Before this I had been using a bool, but that needed if statement to see if speed was a pos/neg value.

But I was just thinking, well this uses now a byte (or 4 in my instance, Unity int32) rather than just one bit.

I know you can cast a bool to int for example but is there a way to store my direction value and use it in the formula like above but only being one bit?

I am using Unity and C#. I realise this is not very important, but just trying to learn if this possible or not.

Comment: There is no structure that can store a bit only, the small unit is one byte and for that you have the `byte` and `sbyte` types.

Comment: OK so i guess my question is how can a byte be used to represent either -1/1 instead of 0/1 (sorry for the noobie approach, I am still trying just to learn)

Comment: This is called "micro-optimization", a.k.a a waste of time

Comment: I realise its not about optimising. Just want to learn if it is possible and therefore learn how to control the engine and language better

Comment: The type `sbyte` is signed, so just assign it +1 or -1.  But this is a silly optimization as it's not really doing anything.

Comment: You can write your own type to do this. However, you need to realize that with _ Value Types_, fields will be initialized to zero. But, you can hide that behavior with properties.  You also have control of implicit and explicit conversion behavior

Comment: This doesn't matter at all .. incontrary it makes your code produce even more garbage -> work for the GC -> more performance intense ... if you store the value as a `bool`/`sbyte` .. but then still have to cast it to an `int` in order to be able to use it for anything -> what do you think you are gaining?

Comment: @derHugo: value types produce no garbage. Creating a simple value type that does what the OP is asking isn't hard. It's also doable with an enum: `public enum : sbyte { Forward = 1, Backward = -1 }`. The problem is that an uninitialized one will always be zero (yeah, enums)

Comment: @Flydog57 of course it s not hard to build one .. you could as well just do `var value = someBool? 1 : -1;`  .. my point was there is not really a point in doing it if OPs goal is saving byte wise memory for the execution of the code ;) also I'm actually not sure on the enum .. afaik they default to the first defined value so in your case `Forward` -> 1 ;)

Comment: @derHugo: Nope, enums are value types, and value types ALWAYS default to the default for the type (which (AFAIK) is always zero or zero-ish (like null)). It's easy to test, and that's what my test shows

Comment: @Flydog57 hm I see, never had to do with an enum where 0 was not the first item tbh :D But I mean since 0 is a valid value for sbyte anyway and this is about a direction I guess having an additional value for 0 actually wouldn't be that bad

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note that modern machines fetch the data as a block of bytes called word, it may be 4 bytes or 8 bytes depending on the architecture.

You can store one bit of information by bit-wise operators but it can only be useful if you multiple bits to pack into one word or byte.

So, if you want to store the direction as a boolean (1 bit of information) then you will have to use if-else statements.
Otherwise, you can't represent the sign as well as the absolute value in just one bit!